# Python isinstance(var, Type) always return False

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django with Python3.
There's a class defined in Model:

```
class PeopleAround(models.Model):
    aaa_Id = models.ForeignKey(Board)
    bbb = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ccc_Id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ddd_Id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

in a view, I'm successfully retrieved some data by following:

```
peopleAroundInDb = PeopleAround.objects.filter(aaa_Id=0).all()
```

and when do a testing, what surprised me is the expression below always return False:

```
isinstance(peopleAroundInDb[0], models.PeopleAround.__class__)
```

and also tested with equality for:

```
id(PeopleAround.__class__) and id(type(peopleAroundInDb[0]))
```

also NOT equal.

so anyone could help?

Comment: Shouldbt be using __class__ instead use actual class name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use `__class__` - as this returns a type object.

Just do this:

```
isinstance(peopleAroundInDb[0], models.PeopleAround)
```

Example:

```
>>> isinstance('text', str.__class__)
False
>>> isinstance('text', str)
True
```

Python doesn't need the class type object to compare, it wants to compare to the class itself.

EDIT:

This technically works:

```
>>> class test:
...     def blah(self, thing):
...         print(isinstance(thing, self.__class__))
...         print(isinstance(thing, test))
...
>>> a = test()
>>> b = test()
>>> a.blah(b)
True
True
```

But I would say that it is clearer, and therefore a better idea, to use `isinstance(thing, test)` over `isinstance(thing, self.__class__)`

Comment: but is this correct use: `(isinstance(other, self.__class__)`?

Comment: @Shawn in this case yes (technically at least) - you're getting the class of the current instance, not the type of the current instance's _class_ (remember that Python's classes are objects too, and as such are instances of another class - named the 'metaclass' -, which by default is the `type` class).

Comment: @Shawn, see my edit. Techincally it works, but it is just clearer to use the class name instead of `self.__class__`.